# How to read cell text when formula is used to calculate the cell

Tags: npoi

We use the .net version on npoi, how do we get the value of of the cell instead of the formula?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little bit confused by your question, as by default NPOI *will* return the value of the cell through the xxxCellValue properties. Consider the next bit of sample code:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"..\..\..\Data\SheetWithFormula.xlsx", FileMode.Open))
{
  var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
  var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);

  var row = sheet.GetRow(2);
  var cell = row.GetCell(2);

  Console.WriteLine("Cell value: {0} (formula: {1})", cell.NumericCellValue, cell.CellFormula);
}
```